# Issue with SSL Certification (getting error: PKIX path building failed)

Tags: soap, ssl

We have an application that tries to connect via SOAP to a third-party application. Last Tuesday, their SSL Certificate expired and they just renewed it again.

However, our code still could not access their endpoint. We still get this error:

```
System.CalloutException: IO Exception: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Now we continued to investigate the issue and here is what we found.

On the actual site (e.g. https://sample-site123.com), there is no issue. The certificate says the site is secure.

[image]

However, when we try to access the endpoint (e.g. https://sample-site123.com/_ws/ActionSample.asmx?op=ActionSample) given to us, this is what we see:

[image]

This is the first time that we've encountered this issue.

Was the certificate not properly configured? The last time the cert was expired, the 3rd-party app team just renewed the certificate and we the SFDC team didn't do anything to change our code.

This is the only clue that we got.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This error is mostly seen when the certificate chain is not in the correct order. Can you try using [SSL checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) and post what error is thrown?

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue-SSL certificate Validation Error
Finally We got it resolved. It is issue with client Server Firewall. It is not allowing the Salesfore url(Site url) we got whitelisted it in all those firewall servers. Then it is working Fine without any errors.
Pls check with your Client IT Team for this Error.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that this is an answer to this question. As sweetha mentioned in the comments, this error is typically due to improper certificate chaining (which in my mind shouldn't have anything to do with firewall rules).